# Express JS pug files attached scss is showing the styling as text within the email

Tags: node.js, express, pug, nodemailer

I am trying to attach a stylesheet file with a `.pug` template sent via email:

```
head
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='../../assets/stylesheets/style.css' type='text/css')
 
.flex.border
  div
    img.banner
  .flex.main-text
    h2 Dear #{username},
    p
      | Welcome to our insurance platform, please click 
      a(href='`#{link}`') here
      |  to activate your account.
      |                 In case you are not being able to click on the activation link, please click on the button below:
    a(href='`#{link}`')
      button.btn(type='button') Click here to activate
    br
    p We are looking forward to work with you.
    p Best Regards,
    p The Insurance Team
```

I tried to use include:

```
head
    include ../../assets/stylesheets/style.css
.flex.border
  div
    img.banner
  .flex.main-text
    h2 Dear #{username},
    p
      | Welcome to our insurance platform, please click 
      a(href='`#{link}`') here
      |  to activate your account.
      |                 In case you are not being able to click on the activation link, please click on the button below:
    a(href='`#{link}`')
      button.btn(type='button') Click here to activate
    br
    p We are looking forward to work with you.
    p Best Regards,
    p The Insurance Team
```

But the email received, contain the `scss` file as text within the email:

[image: pug]

Answer (score 1):

Include the CSS file within a `style` tag. Also, be sure to not forget a `body` element for your contents:

```
head
  style
    include ../../assets/stylesheets/style.css
body
  .flex.border
    div // etc
```